# facing problem to simulate in sumo . how to solve it?

Tags: sumo

Warning: Invalid edge (CONTROL + click to add a disconnected edge) why this is showing

Warning: Invalid edge (CONTROL + click to add a disconnected edge why this is showing on the screen . I can not be able to figure out[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2dhdd.png)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

This error message occurs if you try to build a route in netedit which uses edges in disconnected parts of the network (there is no path from the first edge you clicked to the second). This may show errors in your network input or maybe you have just clicked on the edge for the wrong direction (and turnarounds are forbidden).